# How to read Organised Pointclouds to maintain correspondance between image resolution and cloud width and height?

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library

I am reading the pcd file saved from Zed Camera into PCL point cloud. But I am not able to restore the relation between image point cloud height and width resolution. I am getting a `cloud-> height` as 1 always. I know this happens because some point in the 3D space is not valid hence I am missing them. Does anyone know how to restore the correspondence?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Please try to provide a MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example